# Get process id from process name on Linux (using C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system

What's is the most efficient way to get process id of process by name using c++ code.
I know, I can execute ps -a | grep "proces-name" to do it , is there better way to do it.

Comment: You say "cleanest" and "better", but you forget to say how to measure or compare solutions.

Comment: @j6t It should most efficient and safe way , I'll edit the question.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Here, the problem is to find the pid from the name, not the inverse!

Comment: I have used `top -b -n1` for a long time, but I don't know if it is *better*. Using `pgrep`in an option too.